# Appending data to last row

Tags: excel, vba, append

I have the following VBA query. It copies and pastes data from each of the tabs into the same area, ideally i would like to make it so it appends it to the last row of data on the range. Also the last row of data may not be completely full. Thanks in advance, here is my code:

```vb
Sub CopyData()
    Dim tabNames() As Variant
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim destinationRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim tabName As Variant
    
    ' List of tab names
    tabNames = Array("Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3", "Tab4", "Tab5")
    
    ' Loop through each tab name
    For Each tabName In tabNames
        ' Set the source range to copy
        Set sourceRange = Sheets(tabName).Range("B1:AI6")
        
        ' Loop through the merged cells in the source range and unmerge them
        For Each unmergedCell In sourceRange
            If unmergedCell.MergeCells Then
                unmergedCell.MergeCells = False
            End If
        Next unmergedCell
        
        ' Copy the source range
        sourceRange.Copy
        
        ' Set the destination range for pasting
        Set destinationRange = Sheets("Append").Range("B2")
        
        ' Add a new column with the tab name
        destinationRange.Offset(0, -1).Resize(destinationRange.Rows.Count, 1).Value = tabName
        
        ' Paste the copied data
        destinationRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        
        ' Fill down the tab name column for the entire range
        destinationRange.Offset(0, -1).Resize(destinationRange.Rows.Count + 33, 1).FillDown
        
        ' Clear clipboard
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        ' Get the last row in the destination range
        lastRow = destinationRange.Row + destinationRange.Columns.Count - 1
        
        ' Loop through each row and fill down values in columns B and C
        For i = destinationRange.Row To lastRow
            If IsEmpty(destinationRange.Offset(i - destinationRange.Row, 1)) Then
                destinationRange.Offset(i - destinationRange.Row, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
                destinationRange.Offset(i - destinationRange.Row, 1).Value = destinationRange.Offset(i - destinationRange.Row, 1).Value
            End If
            If IsEmpty(destinationRange.Offset(i - destinationRange.Row, 2)) Then
                destinationRange.Offset(i - destinationRange.Row, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
                destinationRange.Offset(i - destinationRange.Row, 2).Value = destinationRange.Offset(i - destinationRange.Row, 2).Value
            End If
        Next i
    Next tabName
End Sub
```

It copies over the previous data basically only leaving me with one set of results

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this out:

```vb
Sub CopyData()
    Dim tabNames() As Variant
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim destinationRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim tabName As Variant, wb As Workbook, nRows As Long, nCols As Long, rw As Range, n As Long
    
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'or ActiveWorkbook...
    tabNames = Array("Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3", "Tab4", "Tab5")
    
    Set destinationRange = wb.Worksheets("Append").Range("B2") 'first paste goes here
    
    For Each tabName In tabNames
        
        Set sourceRange = wb.Worksheets(tabName).Range("B1:AI6")
        'get the dimensions of the pasted data
        nRows = sourceRange.Columns.Count 'transposing on paste, so r/c are flipped...
        nCols = sourceRange.Rows.Count
        sourceRange.MergeCells = False  '## no need for a loop
        
        destinationRange.Offset(0, -1).Resize(nRows).Value = tabName 'fill in tab name in ColA
        
        sourceRange.Copy
        destinationRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                      SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        
        'fill empty cells in Cols B and C
        For Each rw In destinationRange.Resize(nRows, nCols).Rows
            If rw.Row > destinationRange.Row Then 'skip row#1
                With rw.Cells(1)
                    'no need to set a formula - just copy the value from above
                    If Len(.Value) = 0 Then .Value = .Offset(-1).Value
                End With
                With rw.Cells(2)
                    If Len(.Value) = 0 Then .Value = .Offset(-1).Value
                End With
            End If
        Next rw
        
        Set destinationRange = destinationRange.Offset(nRows) 'next paste destination
        
    Next tabName
End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain your fix.

Comment: There are comments in the code and it's not that different from the original, so I assumed the OP could follow.